# detect and install reportviwer silently with inno setup

Tags: .net, winforms, reportviewer, inno-setup, silent-installer

i am trying to detect and install reportviewer 2005 for a .net 2.0 app i develop silently
i already downloaded reportviewer 2005 redistributable installer and  i have this script

The code to check if reportviewer is installed

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////
// check if report viewer is installed
////////////////////////////////////////////////
function IsReportViewerInstalled(version: string): boolean;
//    'v2.0.50727'          .NET Framework 2.0

var
    key: string;
    install: cardinal;
    success: boolean;
       ErrorCode: Integer;
begin

    // installation all report viewer
    key := 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ReportViewer\' + version;

    success := RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, key, 'Install', install);

    result := success and (install = 1);
end;
```

the code to detect and insall

```
if not IsReportViewerInstalled('v2.0.50727') then  begin
        ExtractTemporaryFile('ReportViewer.exe');
        Log(ExpandConstant('{tmp}\ReportViewer.exe'));
        if ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\ReportViewer.exe'), '','', SW_SHOWNORMAL, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode) then  begin
              Result := True;
           end  else begin
    MsgBox('ReportViewer installation failed. '+SysErrorMessage(ErrorCode), mbError, MB_OK);
              Result := false;
        end;
end else  begin
    result := true;
end;
```

if i run the inno setup in my dev machine which has reportviewer installed, it still pops up reportviewer setup and it does no install silently

what am i doing wrong?

**Edit**

I fount that the parameter to install silen is `ReportViewer.exe /q:a /c:"install.exe /q"`
how do i poass the `/q:a /c:"install.exe /q"` to the shell execute command?

Comment: I don't see parameter to install in silent mode for ReportViewer.exe. You should add specific paremeter (e.g. /q or /silent - you should check which is the correct one for this app). Edit: I have checked: your missing param is `/Q`. So the line will be: `ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\ReportViewer.exe'), '\Q',ExpandConstant('{tmp}'), SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode)`

Comment: i get a command line error when i executed your code `ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\ReportViewer.exe'), '\Q',ExpandConstant('{tmp}'), SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode)`

Comment: Sorry for a typo: should be `/Q`, not `\Q` :(

Comment: it isn't silent, it still pops up the  ReportViewer.exe setup dialog. perhaps am not detecting well

Comment: OK, I have downloaded ReportViewer 2005 and in fact it does not detect parameter correctly. But when I have unpacked (simply unpack with 7z) the ReportViewer.exe I could install the app silently with `install.exe /q`

Comment: what about detecting if it is already installed

Comment: Can you see the reg. key value you query in registry ?

Comment: yes `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ReportViewer\v2.0.50727]
"Install"=dword:00000001`

Comment: Ah, now I see it. Remove that `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` part from the key path. Query only `'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ReportViewer\ + Version'` key. That `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` root key you're passing by `HKLM` in your `RegQueryDWordValue` function call.

Comment: @RobeN this command `install.exe /q` gave a command line error

Comment: Regarding `install.exe /q` I have succesfully installed the app with this command when I had all (41) install files extracted (you will not install the app if you will extract only install.exe; you should have at least one language file, the MSI, INI and CAB files).

Comment: The command stays similar, you just replace parameter `/Q` with your new line `/q:a /c:"install.exe /q"`, although the `ewWaitUntilTerminated` may not work correctly in this case - you should check that on your side. `ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\ReportViewer.exe'), '/q:a /c:"install.exe /q"', ExpandConstant('{tmp}'), SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode)`

Comment: Since you are running an exe file, using `Exec` is better than using `ShellExec`.  The parameters are slightly different but they're similar enough that it's easy to convert between them.  Just read the documentation in the help file..

Comment: @roben can you post the answer so i can marked solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things that you should look at:

1st (thanks to TLama that spotted this issue)

The `Key` string - there is redundant `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\` in string `Value`.

You call `HKLM` branch in `RegQueryDWordValue(HKLM, key, 'Install', install);`

The correct `Key` should be:

`key := 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ReportViewer\' + version;`

---

2nd

You can call the silent install of ReportViewer if you know parameters for command line.

As you know that you shold use `/q:a /c:"install.exe /q"`, you just simply add it in `ShellExec` function:

`ShellExec('', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\ReportViewer.exe'), '/q:a /c:"install.exe /q"', ExpandConstant('{tmp}'), SW_HIDE, ewWaitUntilTerminated, ErrorCode)`